# Azure Front Door Remove Trailing Slashes for Directory Origin

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I am trying to remove trailing slashes in Azure Front Door

So if I user loads `contoso.com/foo`

they will be shown the page at: `origin.azurewebsites.net/foo/index.html`

But currently the source azure web app is redirecting from
`/foo` to `/foo/` per standard IIS rules

So requests for `contoso.com/foo/` load fine however requests for `contoso.com/foo` redirect to `origin.azurewebsites.net/foo/`

I am trying to solve this in Front Door with:

```
Patterns to match:
/foo
/foo/
/bar
/bar/

Origin Path: Empty
```

and

```
Rule Set:

If Condition | Equal | /foo /foo/
Then 
Source Pattern: /
Destination /foo/index.html
Preserve Unmatched Path: No
```

[image]

However the rewritten url goes to:

```
origin.azurewebsites.net/fooindex.html
```

I've tried changing many things in this setup but can't find the solution

If I remove index.html then it simply rewrites to `origin.azurewebsites.net/foo` which redirects to `origin.azurewebsites.net/foo/`

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!